# Print ASCII line art characters in C# console application

Tags: c#

I would like to have a C# console application print the extended ASCII Codes from http://www.asciitable.com/.  In particular I am looking at the line art characters: 169, 170, 179-218.  Unfortunately when I tried, I ended up getting 'Ú' for 218 and expect to see the other characters from http://www.csharp411.com/ascii-table/.

I'm aware that ASCII only specifies character codes 0 - 127.  I found another post with a reference to SetConsoleOutputCP(), but was not able to get that to work in a C# class or find an example of how to do so.

Is it possible to print the line art characters in a C# console application? If it is can someone provide a URL to an example or the code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A small program that modifies the codepage used by the Console.OutputEncoding property to use the characters you desire:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        Console.WriteLine((char) 169);
        Console.WriteLine((char) 170);

        for(char c = (char)179; c <= (char)218; ++c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

So I went ahead and looked up the [Unicode equivalents of the box art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_characters).  There's a few extra glyphs that may be useful to you.  That Wikipedia page lists all of their code points.

I've put together this to try them out:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0x2500; i <= 0x2570; i += 0x10)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c <= 0xF; ++c)
            {
                Console.Write((char) (i + c));
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

For me, quite a few glyphs simply come up as `?`, but the standard box-art glyphs we're used to seeing in the old ASCII games do appear for me.  Hopefully these will work for you.

Comment: I tried 437, didn't work for me.  Code page 1252 yielded the desired extended ASCII characters that he used in his examples.

Comment: This does appear to provide an example of changing the output encoding. Unfortunately I got the original output rather than the line art. @Ron I also tried 437 and had the same results.

Comment: I've tried this on two separate boxes (Windows XP and Windows 7) and was able to get the line art with code page 1252.  Both of these boxes are using US versions of Windows, so not sure what the effects are for different versions of Windows or what the results are under Mono on non-Windows boxes.

Comment: @Joshua Thanks for the feedback I'm on a US version of Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3 for my local development and Windows Server 2008 for "deployment".  I'll test the code on one of the remote servers.

Comment: @Joshua It worked in my remote Server 2008 so I'm going to mark this as answered. I'll continue to see what I can determine about my local XP environment that is not cooperating.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include information about the Unicode equivalents.  Hopefully these will work in more environments.

Comment: @Joshua I was able to reproduce your second set of results in both of my environments with the same "question mark" symbol. That's what I'll use.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

To view correct ascii's on console I just do this:

*`Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);`*

To understand ASCII Chart I wrote below code:

```
using System;

namespace AsciiChart
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
               Console.Write(i+"=> ["+(char)i +"]  \n");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Let's begin to draw, sample 1:**

```
using System;

namespace AsciiBorder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int topleft = 218;
            int hline = 196;
            int topright = 191;
            int vline = 179;
            int bottomleft = 192;
            int bottomright = 217;

            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
            //draw top left corner
            Write(topleft);
            //draw top horizontal line
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                Write(hline);
            //draw top right corner
            Write(topright);
            Console.WriteLine();
            //draw left and right vertical lines
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Write(vline);
                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                WriteLine(vline);
            }
            //draw bottom left coner
            Write(bottomleft);
            //draw bottom horizontal line
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                Write(hline);
            //draw bottom right coner
            Write(bottomright);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void Write(int charcode)
        {
            Console.Write((char)charcode);
        }
        static void WriteLine(int charcode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((char)charcode);
        }
    }
}
```

**Console Output:**

[image]

More info about [Latin 1 & ASCII Code Pages](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs,3b6090c501893c25)

**Completed 3x3 Tic-Tac-Toe like board drawing code: Sample 2**

[image]

**Code:**

```
using System;

namespace AsciiBorder
{
    class Program
    {
        const int topleft = 218, hline = 196, topright = 191, vline = 179, bottomleft = 192, bottomright = 217, cross = 197, topT = 194, bottomT = 193, leftT = 195, rightT = 180;
        const int space = 10/*this determine size of the single cell*/, spacer_ex = (space / 2) + 1;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
            Console.Title = "3x3 Board";
            DrawTop();
            DrawMidSpacer();
            DrawMiddle();
            DrawMidSpacer();
            DrawMiddle();
            DrawMidSpacer();
            DrawBottom();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void DrawBottom() {
            #region bottom
            Write(bottomleft);
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                Write(hline);
            Write(bottomT);
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                Write(hline);
            Write(bottomT);
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                Write(hline);
            Write(bottomright);

            Console.WriteLine();
            #endregion
        }
        static void DrawMiddle() {
            #region middle
            Write(leftT);
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                Write(hline);
            Write(cross);
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                Write(hline);
            Write(cross);
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                Write(hline);
            Write(rightT);

            Console.WriteLine();
            #endregion
        }
        static void DrawMidSpacer() {
            #region middlespacer
            for (int x = 0; x < spacer_ex; x++)
            {
                Write(vline);
                for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                    Console.Write(" ");
                Write(vline);
                for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                    Console.Write(" ");
                Write(vline);
                for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                    Console.Write(" ");
                Write(vline);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            #endregion
        }
        static void DrawTop() {
            #region top
            Write(topleft);
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                Write(hline);
            Write(topT);
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                Write(hline);
            Write(topT);
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++)
                Write(hline);
            Write(topright);

            Console.WriteLine();
            #endregion
        }
        static void Write(int charcode)
        {
            Console.Write((char)charcode);
        }
        static void WriteLine(int charcode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((char)charcode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Signs from the ASCII-table in windows.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("╔═╗");
        Console.WriteLine("╚═╝");
    }
}
```

Comment: This does actually work (at least for me on US Windows 7 in a PowerShell console). Interestingly, it only works properly if using the Console.Write/Writeline methods. If I do a Console.OpenStandardOutput() and then use the resultant stream to write the text, it comes out garbled. I've tried several variations, including changing the OutputEncoding to 1252 before OpeningStandardOutput and also building a StreamWriter that has 1252 encoding when writing to the stdout stream. No luck. I wonder what Console.WriteLine is doing differently.

Comment: Try CP850 instead if using a StreamWriter

Answer (score 1):

I battled this for days a while back. I don't think it can be done, regardless of what other people say. Now, I was trying to make a Dwarf Fortress style game. If you are doing the same, do what he did. Use images.

- Faster, because it can make use of
  graphic acceleration.
- Easier, because they are tiles and
  there are LOTS of tutorials on doing
  that.
- Well Supported, with things like XNA
  for the very framework you are
  already using.
- Extensible, so you can swap in other
  images at a later date, for new
  images like the bearded smiles in DF.

Comment: It's not for a game :(  It's a business application so I need to be able to see the results in a console window and I hope to be able to get similar output to a file for logging / auditing after the fact.

Comment: That's cool. I more answered this for people other than you who might come along.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get ASCII to work but you can use Unicode, to some degree, if you want to. It does require that the console be set to a true type font.

Michael Kaplan's [article](http://www.siao2.com/2010/04/07/9989346.aspx) 'Anyone who says the console can't do Unicode isn't as smart as they think they are' includes the code for this.

I couldn't get his code to work directly but this worked for me as long as I ran it from a True Type Font Console. The article includes how to set it.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace TestUnicode

{
    class Program
{



public static void Main(string[] args) {
    string st = "\u0169\u0129\n\n";
    IntPtr stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    uint written;
    WriteConsoleW(stdout, st, st.Length, out written, IntPtr.Zero);
}


[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern bool WriteConsoleW(IntPtr hConsoleOutput,
                                          string lpBuffer,
                                          int nNumberOfCharsToWrite,
                                          out uint lpNumberOfCharsWritten,
                                          IntPtr lpReserved);


internal static bool IsConsoleFontTrueType(IntPtr std) {
 CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX cfie = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
    cfie.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(cfie);
    if(GetCurrentConsoleFont(std, false, ref cfie)) {
        return(((cfie.FontFamily & TMPF_TRUETYPE) == TMPF_TRUETYPE));
    }
    return false;
}



[DllImport("Kernel32.DLL", ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);


[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool GetCurrentConsoleFont(IntPtr hConsoleOutput,
                                                    bool bMaximumWindow, 
                                                    ref CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);



internal struct COORD {
    internal short X;
    internal short Y;
    internal COORD(short x, short y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal unsafe struct CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX {
    internal uint cbSize;
    internal uint nFont;
    internal COORD dwFontSize;
    internal int FontFamily;
    internal int FontWeight;
    fixed char FaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
}

internal const int TMPF_TRUETYPE = 0x4;
internal const int LF_FACESIZE = 32;
internal const string BOM = "\uFEFF";
internal const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11; // Handle to the standard output device.
internal const int ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE = 6;
internal const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
internal const uint FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN = 0x0000;
internal const uint FILE_TYPE_DISK = 0x0001;
internal const uint FILE_TYPE_CHAR = 0x0002;
internal const uint FILE_TYPE_PIPE = 0x0003;
internal const uint FILE_TYPE_REMOTE = 0x8000;
internal static IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);
}
    }
```

Comment: I'm using VS 2010 and getting an Error "Unsafe code may only appear if compiing with /unsafe.  I'll have to look that one up.

Comment: OK, after changing the project properties on the build tab to allow unsafe code I got the project to run, but still don't believe I see what I'm looking for.

Comment: You need to run it from a Console that is set to a True Type Font So running the project directly from VS won't work. The article I linked to describes how to set the font.

Comment: my console font defaults to Lucida Console. I did look at the article, but I didn't build and run. I'll try that... I got the same results as before unfortunately.  It may be something with my environment.