# c# console application using microsoft visual studio 2010, is it possible to include a logo

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

im making and auction system using c# on visual studio 2010, im just wondering if it is possible to include a logo/image throughout my console. as a company logo as or something.

Comment: you mean a background picture for the console?

Comment: You could use a forms app that is essentially a big console with a background/watermark on the text window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Console applications aren't primarily intended to display graphics or images you might find some joy in implementing ASCII art - http://chris.com/ascii/ .

You could possibly implement a menu system that ensures the logo you design is displayed at the top of the console window at all times, with the menu options following downwards from it.

The following question may be of some use to you - [Printing ASCII line art characters in a C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511098/print-ascii-line-art-characters-in-c-console-application)

Comment: thats great that thankyou, you any idea how i put it the ASCII into the actual console. not to sure about the code needed to display it

Comment: I think there's some sample code in the last link I posted, I've personally never tried using ASCII code I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

No, the console window is by definition text-only.

(You can create an additional window, or rewrite as a Windows Forms or WPF app.)

Comment: thanks for that, im going to try and use an ASCII instead like the comment below :)