# Is possible to add warning symbol in C#?

Tags: c#

i want to ask if is possible to add in a string the "⚠" character and make it executable in console with `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: Perhaps you can get idea from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511098/print-ascii-line-art-characters-in-c-sharp-console-application

Comment: You should check: [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code;

```
System.Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Console.WriteLine("⚠");
```