# what is ASCII code for right filled arrow " ►"

Tags: c#, char, ascii

I am trying to print right filled arrow ► in C# this is I tried

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
   Console.WriteLine((char)16);
 }
```

but it is showing the output as `?` (question mark)
I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511098/print-ascii-line-art-characters-in-c-sharp-console-application) question also but the it doesn't seem to work.
Can you help me with correct ASCII code which shows the correct output?

Comment: Console uses another code page than a windows text box. Just hit Win+R and type "charmap" there you get character tables in windows.

Comment: It's not in ASCII. It's unicode codepoint U+25BA. So `"\u25ba"` would work.

Comment: Not in a Console window, right?

Comment: @Grisgram Well, that depends on the encoding of the console...

Comment: @Sweeper that depends on the **font** of the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily convert `char` to `int` and thus obtain its *code*:

```
  char arrow = '►'; // Copy + Paste from the question

  Console.Write($"{arrow} : {(int)arrow} : \\u{(int)arrow:X4}";);
```

Outcome:

```
  ► : 9658 : \u25BA
```

and that's why you can put

```
  char arrow = '\u25BA';
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the console output encoding before printing:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
Console.WriteLine((char)9658);
// or just
//Console.WriteLine('►');
```

Answer (score 3):

The black filled arrow is not included in the ascii charset. You need to use unicode.

In your example:

```
string myString = "\u25BA";
Console.WriteLine(myString);
```

You also need to be aware that the font you use can display the specific unicode character. As far as i know the default console font does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 5+ the following code is relevant:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine("↑▲");
```