# How to write our content in a table using c language. like how to display our content in a table with rows and column

Tags: c

Without using graphics.h library how to make a table in C program and display our content in that table. It should have table borders around the data and the content should be within it. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: If you don't want to use any graphics libraries, [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) is your only hope.

Comment: There is a character chart in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45221670/4142924) which shows border symbols available. You have to select the right code page to get them, because they are non-ASCII characters in the range 128-255.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: windows 10 operating system

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example working in Windows console using the default *Terminal* font. The accented characters are valid ones which are represented by corners, borders and lines.

Output is:

[image]

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍËÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»\n");
    printf("º %11s º %11s º\n", "Hello", "World");
    printf("ÌÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÎÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¹\n");
    printf("º %11s º %11s º\n", "Welcome", "you");
    printf("ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÊÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼\n");
}
```

To find the characters, use the [character map tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map_(Windows)) of windows and select *terminal* font. You can copy/paste characters.